# Timezone issue in GXT?

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using below code.

```
private DateField startDateField = new DateField();
Date date = new Date();
startDateField.setValue(date);

Date date2 =startDateField.getValue()
```

The problem is, when i call startDateField.getValue()  method i am getting date but time is set 0. my server is in KOP. i am passing date as IST. as GWT does adjustments of dates based on timezone. KOP is in different timezone. if i pass date in IST then it should take exactly matching KOP time? Please suggest me.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably it'll do the conversion with its default locale (IST for your web application, KOP for the server). So, depends on where you run your code. But thinking about it again... couldn't it be that it just cuts off the time in your above example? Just throws it away, no conversion at all... because the Java spec doesn't say anything about locales for the Date class. That's handled by the DateFormat and Calendar classes.